# Connecting Seeeduino XIAO 3.3 V out to dual H-bridge driver module (L298N) with TTL compatible inputs

Tags: h-bridge

The H-bridge module uses TTL compatible logic, but the chip allows these values (based on the [L298N data sheet](https://datasheets.diptrace.com/st_micro/CD00000240.pdf)):

| Symbol | Parameter | Min. | Max. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| V<sub>iL</sub> | Input Low Voltage (pin 5, 7, 10, and 12) | -0.3 V | 1.5 V |
| V<sub>iH</sub> | Input High Voltage (pin 5, 7, 10, and 12) | 2.3 V | V<sub>SS</sub> |

Am I correct to assume that I do not need to step-up the logic signal (from 3.3 V to 5 V) for this to work, but can I connect straight to the input?

Schematic in mind:

[image]

Comment: You are you using the Seedstudio L298N board, right? not the bare L298N? That board have pull-up resistors on the it, that pull to 5V. Not sure what 5V through a 10kOhm resistor does the the IO pin on a 3.3V MCU. It's probably fine, and it's only an issue while the pin is an INPUT, which it only is till you run your code (only during bootloader and startup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I correct to assume that I do not need to step-up the logic signal (from 3.3V to 5V) for this to work, but can connect straight to the input?

You are correct. The input has to be above 2.3V to register as HIGH and below 1.5V to register as LOW. You have 3.3V for HIGH and near 0V for LOW, which fits those criteria perfectly.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to add "Seeeduino XIAO" as tag but do not have enough points, can you do that? I think it would help.

Comment: @MeSo2 No, I won't do that. If we added every board that existed as a tag we'd overload the database. Only the main Arduino boards and very common third party boards ones have tags. The Xiao isn't a common one - I have never heard of it.

Comment: Comparatively recent small form factor board using the same chip as the various "zero" boards.  XIAO, specifically, doesn't really enter into the actual question though where its role is just as a 3.3v logic level MCU.

Comment: @timemage So, it's YAABB...  Yet *Another* ARM Based Board...

Comment: Yes, though it *seems* to be gaining a following; it *may* eventually warrant a tag for dealing with its actual eccentricities.  Perhaps not yet.

Comment: @timemage Maybe I should add the tag "yaabb" ;)

Comment: Could not resist up-voting that. =)

Comment: **@timemage** "For general I/O pins: Working voltage of MCU is 3.3V. Voltage input connected to general I/O pins may cause chip damage if it' higher than 3.3V." found here: [Seeeduino XIAO](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Seeeduino-XIAO/)

Comment: @Majenko is there any issue with the Seedstudio L298N board having pull-up resistors to 5V.

Comment: @Gerben typically there's no problem. The resistor drops the current to 170uA which is far below the rating of most ESD protection diodes... (looking at the SAMD21 datasheet 1mA is the worst case minimum, and 720uA is below that.)

Comment: @MeSo2, I get that, but I'm unclear on *why* you're saying this to me.

Comment: @timemage I think he's confusing input and output....

Comment: @Majenko, if I had to guess, I'd say he may be under the impression that a XIAO is somehow different from an Arduino Zero (which uses the same microcontroller) with respect to the 3.3v signals; it isn't.

Comment: @timemage XIAO pin 1, 2, 8 - 11 will be used as outputs. I never used an Arduino, but got my feet wet using a propeller microcontroller back in 2014.